# Output friends list to json (include ID) with Mogli

Tags: ruby, json, facebook

I'd like to convert the friends list to json (include both names and id's).

Here is what I have... But it results in only a list of names.

```
@client = Mogli::Client.new(session[:at])
@app  = Mogli::Application.find(ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"], @client)
@user = Mogli::User.find("me", @client)

@user.friends.to_json
```

How do I also include the users ID?